# Approximate minimum of function

Tags: optimization, approximation

Let:
$$f(\Delta)=\sqrt{b \log ^n\left(\frac{E}{\Delta
   }\right)+4\frac{\Delta ^2}{E^2}},\ \ n=4,6$$
$$E,b,\Delta>0,\ \ \Delta \ll E$$

The function has a single minimum, but the explicit expression is difficult to find. Can an approximate location for the minimum of $f(\Delta)$ be found in terms of $E,b$?

Comment: Should we assume $b,E,\Delta \gt 0$? Have you considered dropping the square root? (It's monotonic.)

Comment: @hardmath - yes. You can also assume $\Delta\ll E$, and I don't see how dropping the sqrt helps.

Comment: Am I correct thinking that $b$ should be very samll ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - yes, I think so. Let's assume $b \ll 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you don't understand that the square root can be dropped, or you don't agree that dropping it simplifies the calculation.  The minimum of $f(\Delta)$ will be attained at the same $\Delta$ that minimizes $f^2$, so generally we expect working with $f^2$ to give a little easier work to find the same approximations to $\Delta$.

Here's my take.  We substitute $x=\log(E/\Delta)$ into $f^2 = b \log^n \left(\frac{E}{\Delta}\right) + 4 \frac{\Delta^2}{E^2}$:

$$ g(x) = bx^n + 4e^{-2x} $$

The assumption that $\Delta \ll E$ means $x \gt 0$, so we can proceed with the usual setting of $g'(x)$ to zero to identify its minimum (critical point) on $(0,\infty)$.

$$ g'(x) = nb x^{n-1} - 8e^{-2x} $$

Thus $g'(x)=0$ occurs when:

$$ x^{n-1} e^{2x} = \frac{8}{nb} $$

While the left hand side doesn't have a convenient (functional) inverse, for $n=4,6$ it is monotone increasing on $(0,\infty)$.  We don't have any information about the magnitude of $b$, but a narrow approximation of the minimizing $x$ (and thus of $\Delta$) can be extracted with a little work.  First check to see if $x=1$ is too high or too low, ie. check if $e^2$ is above or below $\frac{8}{nb}$.  It seems likely, given that $\Delta \ll E$, that you would expect $x \gt 1$, but this is easy to check.

I would then do some fixed-point iterations of:

$$ h(x) = \frac{\log{8} - \log{nb} - (n-1)\log(x)}{2} $$

starting from $x_0 = 1$, noting that $h(x)=x$ implies $x$ solves the critical point equation for $g'(x)=0$.

---

I understand that an (easily-computed) analytic approximation for the minimum value is sought, but let me at least point out that the exact location where the minimum occurs can be expressed in terms of [the Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  Taking the $n-1$ root of both sides of the critical point equation:

$$ x e^{\frac{2x}{n-1}} = \sqrt[n-1]{\frac{8}{nb}} $$

Thus $x = \left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right) W\left( \left( \frac{2}{n-1} \right)
  \sqrt[n-1]{\frac{8}{nb}} \right) $, and from $x = \log E - \log \Delta$ the exact minimizing value of $\Delta$ can be determined.

---

As we already see from the critical point equation, $x$ will be uniquely determined by $B = 8/nb$, so given that $n=4,6$, the assumption that $b \ll 1$ would say that $B \gg 1$.  Of course the left-hand side $x^{n-1}e^{2x}$ is a rapidly increasing monotone function on $[0,\infty)$.  One step of our proposed fixed-point iteration ($x_0 = 1$) gives $x_1 = \log(B)/2$, which is an overestimate of the actual root/critical point.

One idea would be to plug this first iteration back into the function, and get a better approximation $x_2 = h(\log(B)/2)$.  It is [well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/456854/3111) that if $|h'(x_k)| \le \alpha \lt 1$, then the iteration is [a contraction map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) and converges at least linearly.  To investigate from this point of view:

$$ h'(x) = \frac{1-n}{2x} $$

so that $|h'(x)| < 1$ in a neighborhood of root $x$ if and only if $x \gt (n-1)/2$.

Recall that the critical point equation allows us to verify easily if this is so:

$$ \text{root } x \gt (n-1)/2 \iff 4^{n-1} e^8 \lt \frac{8}{nb} = B $$

Therefore if this condition holds, e.g. if $b \lt 4^{4-n} e^{-8} n^{-1}$, then a sequence of analytic approximations that converge to the root $x$ is:

$$ \frac{n-1}{2}, h\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right), h\left(h\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)\right), \ldots $$

---

If $b$ is not small enough, or if the sequence developed above doesn't converge rapidly enough for the (unstated) purpose, then perhaps an alternative approach based on the exact solution $x$ in terms of Lambert W (above) is more attractive.  [Numerical evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Numerical_evaluation) of Lambert W by Newton's method or by Halley's method (cubic convergence) turns out to be [surprisingly elegant](http://yacas.sourceforge.net/Algochapter6.html).  For series and related iterative methods, see [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?rep=rep1&type=pdf&doi=10.1.1.33.4150) and [here](http://www.whim.org/nebula/math/lambertw.html).

Comment: if we're going to use fixed-point iterations, I could do that to the original equation as well, I was trying to see if I could come up with an approximate analytic form.

Comment: @nbubis: Perhaps you could give me a specific $b$ and I can show how this gives an analytic approximation.

Comment: I think we can assume $b \ll 1$. Does that help?

Comment: Sure, as you can see from the rewriting of the problem, $E$ and $\Delta$ can be paired off into new variable $x$, so the real driver of the solution is $b$ (as well as $n$, but you specified $n=4,6$ as a couple of values to handle).

Answer (score 0):

Approximate the function $f$ by some low degree polynomial, whose coefficients will be functions of $E$ and $b$. Locate the minimum of this polynomial, and use it as an approximation of the minimum of $f$.

Comment: Tried that, it doesn't give very good results. I'd be glad to be proven otherwise.